# AS2 - How do you remove part of a string

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2

I want a simple function that can remove part of a string, eg:

```
var foo="oranges";
trace(removeStrings(foo,'rang'));
```

I want the above output as 'oes'. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can write removeStrings using [substr()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001557.html), [substring()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001558.html) or other [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/00001546.html#480347) methods

Answer (score 4):

A quick solution for removing substrings is to use `split` with the string that you want to remove as delimiter and then `join` the result:

```
function removeSubString(str, remove):String {
    return str.split(remove).join("");
}
```

Comment: if you do not want to replace what you remove with a comma (","), the join method needs "" passed to it, making it:

return str.split(remove).join("");

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is

```
  function removeStrings(originalString, pattern):String
  {
        return originalString.replace(pattern, "");
  }
```

For more information about Strings in AS3 you can visit:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html

I should mention that the code above is not going to change your String, so if you need to use the property originalString with the new value you should use:

```
  originalString = removeStrings(originalString, pattern);
```

The second thing that I should mention is that the replace method will replace the first appearance of the pattern, so if you need to replace every match of the pattern you should do something like

```
 while(originalString.search(pattern) != -1)
 {
       originalString = removeStrings(originalString, pattern);
 }
```

Hope this will help!
Ivan Marinov

Comment: I'm sorry, I had some errors in the code. It seems that I was a little bit abson-minded when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Well, it seems I've been a lot of abson-minded because the question is about AS2 and I'm not sure if this is fine for AS2. I will check out and will refine my answer.

Comment: Well in AS2 there is no such method replace, so the previous answer is just the fine for you :) You can find more information about the strings (and about the whole AS2) in http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using by long time this snippet, which as the advantage to be available to all string objects on your movie:

```
String.prototype.replace = function(pattern, replacement) {
  return this.split(pattern).join(replacement);
}
```

can be used in this way:

```
var str = "hello world";
var newstr = str.replace("world", "abc");
trace(newstr);
```

as you can see the string class have been extended with the `replace` method.